# Daily iframe content with auto resize

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need Daily iFrame content script with auto resize.
I've been tried many ways to get that. But nah.

Here is full code (http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/dowiframe.htm):

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //ID of Daily Iframe tag:
        var iframeids = ["dynstuff"]

        var getFFVersion = navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split("/")[1]
        var FFextraHeight = getFFVersion >= 0.1 ? 16 : 0 //extra height in px to add to iframe in FireFox 1.0+ browsers

        function startdyncode() {
            dyniframesize()
        }

        function dyniframesize() {
            var dyniframe = new Array()
            for (i = 0; i < iframeids.length; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById) { //begin resizing iframe procedure
                    dyniframe[dyniframe.length] = document.getElementById(iframeids[i]);
                    if (dyniframe[i] && !window.opera) {
                        dyniframe[i].style.display = "block"
                        if (dyniframe[i].contentDocument && dyniframe[i].contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) //ns6 syntax
                            dyniframe[i].height = dyniframe[i].contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + FFextraHeight;
                        else if (dyniframe[i].Document && dyniframe[i].Document.body.scrollHeight) //ie5+ syntax
                            dyniframe[i].height = dyniframe[i].Document.body.scrollHeight;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", startdyncode, false)
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", startdyncode)

    </script>

    <script language="JavaScript1.2">

        //Daily iframe content- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
        //For full source code, and Terms Of use, visit http://dynamicdrive.com
        //This credit MUST stay intact for use

        var ie = document.all && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") == -1
        var dom = document.getElementById && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") == -1

        //Specify IFRAME display attributes
        var iframeprops = 'width=150 height=150 marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="1" scrolling="no"'

        //Specify 7 URLs to display inside iframe, one for each day of week
        var daycontent = new Array()
        daycontent[1] = "monday.htm" //Monday content
        daycontent[2] = "tuesday.htm" //Tuesday content
        daycontent[3] = "wednesday.htm"
        daycontent[4] = "thursday.htm"
        daycontent[5] = "friday.htm"
        daycontent[6] = "saturday.htm"
        daycontent[0] = "sunday.htm"

        //No need to edit after here
        if (ie || dom)
            document.write('<iframe id="dynstuff" src="" ' + iframeprops + '></iframe>')

        var mydate = new Date()
        var mytoday = mydate.getDay()

        function dayofweek_iframe() {
            if (ie || dom) {
                var iframeobj = document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("dynstuff") : document.all.dynstuff
                iframeobj.src = daycontent[mytoday]
            }
        }

        window.onload = dayofweek_iframe

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Auto resize doesn't work with that code. What I have to do?

Can somebody help?

Comment: we could need some code to see what your mistake is.

Comment: I added codes there.

Comment: if you could format it properly, it would be easier to understand it.

Comment: Now I added only full code.